# Scala: Type mismatch with nested generics

Tags: scala, generics, types

I've created the contrived example below to show what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm looking for a factory that will spit out a class which is parameterized with the specific type of request it will process. I thought I understood generics but now I'm doubting myself. :)

```
object SourceFactory {
  def apply[T <: Source[_ <: RequestContext]](x: String): Source[_ <: RequestContext] = { 
    x match {
      case "a" => new FooSource
    }   
  }
}

object RequestContextFactory {
  def apply[T >: RequestContext](x: String): T = { 
    x match {
      case "a" => FooRequestContext()
    }   
  }
}

abstract class RequestContext
case class FooRequestContext() extends RequestContext

abstract class Source[T <: RequestContext] {
  def get(ctx: T): Unit
}

class FooSource extends Source[FooRequestContext] {
  def get(ctx: FooRequestContext): Unit = {}
}

object Test extends App {
  val source = SourceFactory("a")
  val ctx = RequestContextFactory("a")

  source.get(ctx)
}
```

Results in:

> Compiler exception error: line 32: type mismatch;
>    found   : Evaluator__da15fb805d29b29227bc28ccae6cd07d2c04cb40_1274353927.Test.ctx.type (with underlying type RequestContext)
>    required: _$2
>         source.get(ctx)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scala has absolutely no way to infer `T` in either `SourceFactory.apply` or `RequestContextFactory.apply`, because it doesn't appear in the arguments. You are calling `SourceFactory[Nothing]` and `RequestContextFactory[RequestContext]` (and the second only because of a probable typo in `def apply[T >: RequestContext]`).

You can give `T` explicitly:

```
object SourceFactory {
  def apply[T <: RequestContext](x: String): Source[T] = { 
    (x match {
      case "a" => new FooSource
    }).asInstanceOf[Source[T]]
  }
}

object RequestContextFactory {
  def apply[T <: RequestContext](x: String): T = { 
    (x match {
      case "a" => FooRequestContext()
    }).asInstanceOf[T]   
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  val source = SourceFactory[FooRequestContext]("a")
  val ctx = RequestContextFactory[FooRequestContext]("a")

  source.get(ctx)
}
```

Note how you end up needing casts: this should hint that this is a bad design! The problem is that your return *type* depends on the *value* of the argument. Scala does support a form of this called path-dependent types, but it isn't applicable here. You could also try to remove the type parameters and use only existentials:

```
object SourceFactory {
  def apply(x: String): Source[_ <: RequestContext] = { 
    x match {
      case "a" => new FooSource
    }
  }
}

object RequestContextFactory {
  def apply(x: String): RequestContext = { // equivalent to _ <: RequestContext
    x match {
      case "a" => FooRequestContext()
    }
  }
}

object Test extends App {
  val source = SourceFactory("a")
  val ctx = RequestContextFactory("a")

  source.get(ctx)
}
```

Not there are no casts in `SourceFactory` or `ResourceContextFactory`, but neither is there any relationship between their return types, so `source.get(ctx)` won't compile!

What might actually work, depending on your requirements, is to pair the return values into a single type:

```
case class SourceAndRequestContext[T <: RequestContext](src: Source[T], ctx: T) {
  def get() = src.get(ctx)
}

object SourceAndRequestContextFactory {
  def apply(x: String): SourceAndRequestContext[_ <: RequestContext] = x match {
    case "a" => SourceAndRequestContext(new FooSource, FooRequestContext())
  }
}
```